# Four cards are face down on a table.

Tags: probability

Four cards are face down on a table. You are told that two are red and two are black, and you need to guess which two are red and which two are black. You do this by pointing to the two cards you’re guessing are red (and then implicitly you’re guessing that the other two are black). Assume that all configurations are equally likely, and that you do not have psychic powers. Find the probability that exactly j of your guesses are correct, for j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

- I know the answers and calculations for each of the five probabilities: j=0: 1/6, j=1: 0, j=2: 2/3, j=3: 0, j=4: 1/6 but I do not understand where the numbers are coming from. What do the j numbers have to do with anything? Can someone please explain to me the thinking process of solving this problem? I am just extremely confused as to what the js have to do with anything and why the probability is only zero on odd numbers and why j=2 is different than j=0 and j=4.

Comment: $j$ is the random variable detailing how many of your *four* guesses you got right.  We are not only guessing which cards are red, we are *also* guessing which cards are black.  Suppose the true arrangement was RRBB and I guessed that the red cards were in positions $1$ and $3$ (*and so as a result also guessed that the black cards were in positions $2$ and $4$*).  I will have been correct that the first position was red, I will have been incorrect about the second position being black, incorrect about the third position being red, and correct about the fourth position being black, so here j=2

Comment: You should be able to see that it is impossible to get an odd number of correct guesses here since if you pointed to two red cards you are also getting points for the black cards too and so get four points.  If you pointed to one red and one black card, among the not-pointed-to cards there is a black card and so you get a total of two points (one for the pointed to red, one for the not-pointed-to black*).  If you pointed to zero reds, then both of the not-pointed-to cards were red and so you got zero points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Four cards are face down on a table. You are told that two are red and two are black, and you need to guess which two are red and which two are black.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822822/four-cards-are-face-down-on-a-table-you-are-told-that-two-are-red-and-two-are-b)

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose $2$ cards from the $4$.

Among these, there is exactly $1$ way to choose $2$ red cards and $1$ way to choose $2$ black cards, yielding a probability of $\frac16$ in each case.

The remaining case is choosing one of each colour of cards. There are $2\times2=4$ (or $6-2=4$) ways to achieve this, yielding a probability of $\frac23$.

Now to link these probabilities to $j$.

If we chose $2$ red cards, we get them all right, and $j=4$.

If we chose $2$ black cards, we get them all wrong, and $j=0$.

If we chose one of each, one of our chosen cards is red and one of our cards not chosen is black, so we have $j=2$.

You cannot get an odd number of cards wrong. Whenever you make a mistake in your chosen cards, you also make one in the unchosen ones. In fact, the number of red cards in your chosen pile is always equal to the number of black cards in the unchosen pile.

Answer (score 0):

The j numbers matter because there is a higher probability of getting exactly 2 correct guesses than there is of getting all of the guesses correct.

Notice also that guessing them all correct has the same probability as guessing them all wrong. Furthermore, we can say that $P_n(j)=P_n(2n-j)$, where $n$ is the number of red cards (and therefore black cards) and $P_n(j)$ is the probability of getting exactly $j$ correct guesses given $n$ red cards and $n$ black cards.

The last thing to show that $P_n(j)=0$ when $j$ is odd. This is the same as showing that you can never get an odd number of correct guesses. Since the number of red guesses you make is a constant, equal to $n$, then every possible guessing scheme can be created by repeatedly switching the position of one of your red guesses with the position of one your black guesses.

There are 3 cases: both of your guesses were initially correct, both of them were wrong, or one of them was right. If both of your guesses were initially correct, then when you switch them they will both be wrong, and vice versa. This means that in these 2 cases, your score will either go +2 or -2. In the case of one of your guesses being initially correct, since you are switching different colored guesses, this means that the 2 cards you guessed were the same color. So when you flip the positions of your 2 guesses, the guess in the other position will be correct and the other one will be wrong. So your score does not change. So of the 3 possible non-redundant moves, all of them result in an even change to your score. Since the maximum is $2n$, an even number, this means all attainable scores must also be even numbers.

Now let's try to figure out how to calculate $P_n(j)$ when $j$ is even. The only possible way to get a score of $j$ is to get exactly $\frac{j}{2}$ red guesses correctly and consequently $\frac{j}{2}$ of your black guesses will be correct. There are $\binom{n}{j/2}$ ways to get exactly $\frac{j}{2}$ red guesses correctly and there are $\binom{n}{j/2}$ ways to get exactly $\frac{j}{2}$ black guesses correctly. There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ total ways to guess. So $P_n(j)=\frac{n!^4}{(2n)!(j/2)!^2(n-j/2)!^2}$.

So in your case $P_2(0)=P_2(4)=\frac{16}{24*4}=\frac{1}{6}$ and $P_2(2)=\frac{16}{24}=\frac{2}{3}$. If there were 6 cards, then we would have $P_3(0)=P_3(6)=\frac{36}{20*36}=\frac{1}{20}$, $P_3(2)=P_3(4)=\frac{36}{20*4}=\frac{9}{20}$

An additional thing we can do is prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} P_n(2k)=1$. This is equivalent to $\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k}$. We can use vandermonde's identity, to see that this simplifies to $\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}*\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=1$